# Calculating angle between two lines in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, angle

I am trying to calculate the angle between two lines in my program. I have their `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` for both lines. The first line's `x2` and `y2`, is the same as the second line's `x1` and `y1`.

I am using the `Point2D` from the JavaFX library.

I need to calculate the angle in order to know which way to turn -> e.g to write "turn left" or "turn right". I know which point is my starting point, mid point, and end point.

I have tried all methods I have been able to find online, but none works. I always get either 0.0 or 180 degrees.

I would like a method that always takes the clockwise angle going out from line 1 (Or counterclockwise), no matter if it's going up or down in the coordinate system or left to right.

I keep reading about the `Math.atan2` function, but I don't understand how to interpret the result, or if it works for my problem.

This is what I am trying right now:

```
    Point2D vectorFrom = new Point2D(c.getX2() - c.getX1(), - (c.getY2() - 
    c.getY1()));

    Point2D vectorTo = new Point2D(n.getX2() - n.getX1(), - (n.getY2() - 
    n.getY1()));

    double direction1 = Math.atan2(vectorFrom.getX(), vectorFrom.getY());
    double direction2 = Math.atan2(vectorTo.getX(), vectorTo.getY();
    double angle = direction2 - direction1;`
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried exactly. You might find it helpful to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi thanks, I have edited my question now to show my latest attempt. :)

Comment: "_I would like a method that always takes the clockwise angle going out from line 1 (Or counterclockwise), no matter if it's going up or down in the coordinate system or left to right._" this is not very clear. Consider addin a sketch and test data.

Answer (score 1):

the atan2 method permit to calculate the angle between a segment of your choice and the horizontal axis, so if you put some absolute value, it might works as is. otherwise you can use the Point2D method `vector1.angle(vector2)` which gives you the angle between both vector

giving you

```
double angle=vectorFrom.angle(vectorTo)
```